# Custom Config of GitVersion with VSTS

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, gitversion

I'm currently trying to do some custom configuration with GitVersion on my VSTS repository (Would like to be able to bumb major versions by adding a specific commit message), but i can't seem to get VSTS to accept any custom configuration.

It's running on a hosted machine where i'm pulling a fresh copy of the repository on each build. So when i'm building i would like it to execute my GitVersion task.

i can get it to run GitVersion, just doesn't seem to do anything or catch my config.

Any ideas? 
Note for this i'm fairly new to VSTS and GitVersion.

Cheers!

Comment: How are you determining it's "not working"?  What are you expecting to happen.  Can you attach a screeshot of the configuration of your GitVersion task?  Out-of-the-box GitVersion task is at the very least going to update your build name to state the specific version detected, do you see that at the very least?

Comment: Which GitVersion you used? [GitVersionTask package](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build-server-support/build-server/tfs-build-vnext/), [GitVersion extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gittools.gitversion) or other? Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive? (Set system.debug variable to true, then queue build and share this log)

Comment: @raterus I can determine it isn't working by i have manually tried to upload a version of GitVersion so i could use my on configuration. Then i have tried to manually set the config and upload that to bumb then Major patch number. with no results, since it falls back on a default GitVersion i think

Comment: Can you share the log on the OneDrive?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT Yes, i had to make sure about the policy of sharing such things.

https://1drv.ms/t/s!Ai0ieQUxSjDGiTSPmNQie8Ad5zIP

Comment: You said that "Would like to be able to bumb major versions by adding a specific commit message", do you mean you want to update the major version per to commit message? On the other hand, you said custom configuration, is there GitVersion.yml file in current branch repository?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT Ideally the idea would be that it bumps a minor patch on every merge to master, but would bump a major version automaticly if some specified text is present in the commit message.

Edit: Here's a picture of my current repository. it's specificly made to test this GitVersioning https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ai0ieQUxSjDGiTUJ6B6VmnZc22zE

Comment: Do you check these articles? http://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#version-sources and http://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more-info/version-increments/#manually-incrementing-the-version?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT Yes, i have, but it doesn't seems like i can get it to act on my GitVersion.yml configuration. 

`assembly-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatch
mode: ContinuousDeployment
next-version: 2.0.0
branches:
  master: {}
  features?[/-]: {}
ignore:
  sha: [] `

Or is it me missing something? This is my very basic config i've been trying to get it to run. With the logs i posted earlier

Answer (score 0):

Based on the test result, you need to put GitVersion.yml file to the root repository.